# How to prevent to adding two lists in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

How to Prevent adding two controls or to lists ? I've tried this code but it doesn't work... Pease help!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        ViewState["check"] = "First_Time";
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["check"] == "First_Time")
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        ViewState["check"] = "Scond_Time";
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Sorry, Can't create a list on second time");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to clarify what you are asking?  Right now it is a little unclear.  What does "Prevent adding two controls or to lists" mean?  Are you sure you are using `to` and `two` correctly?

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing the ViewState check?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that the button click event is triggered on postback, hence your postback check in `Page_Load` is pointless.

Since the [`CheckBoxList.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are stored in `Viewstate` by default(it implements [`IStateManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.istatemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), why don't you simply check if the items are already added?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBoxList1.Items.Count < 6)
    {
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // don't use Response.Write to output messages but controls
        Response.Write("Sorry, Can't create a list on second time");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim! I understand "The problem with your approach is that the button click event is triggered on postback, hence your postback check in Page_Load is pointless"

But how can i solve this point? because i want to learn about it to use that concept in many other codes...

Comment: You don't need an additional Viewstate variable at all as shown above. So I don't understand the problem.